# Is it possible to force BIOS mode (as opposed to UEFI) in the installer?

Tags: boot, uefi

On a laptop where I already have elementary OS 5 installed in BIOS mode (no /boot/efi partition), I am trying to install elementary OS 6 from USB, and I would like to keep the system booting in BIOS, not UEFI, mode. However, the installer always insists on a separate /boot/efi partition in the partitioning step. (This is not the case on another laptop where I tried installing, where just a / partition was sufficient.) I checked the BIOS boot settings, and it's set to Legacy Support (Legacy First). I tried searching for an installer boot option to force BIOS mode but did not come to something. Any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After researching, it seems that remastering the ISO and deleting the EFI directory would have been the simplest approach. However, I admit my issue turned out to be that the boot USB was showing up twice in the boot menu, and I was selecting the one that boots in UEFI mode, not legacy mode.